# knockout mapping jquery

Tags: jquery, json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

in my script, i have this:

```
$('#divForm').load('../Reservation/Edit #EditReservation', function () {
    $('#divForm').slideDown(500), function () { };
    var viewModel = {};
    var id = JSON.stringify(rowid);
    $.post("/Reservation/JsonEdit", { jsonId: id }, function (data) {
        var trueData = JSON.stringify(data);
        alert(trueData);
        viewModel.model = ko.mapping.fromJSON(trueData);
        alert("chkpt1");
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        alert("chkpt2");
    });
});
```

this script runs until "chkpt1" and it does not execute: ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
            alert("chkpt2");

i am using this script in this cshtml:

```
<div id="EditReservation" >
<div data-bind="foreach: model.Room">
    <div style="margin-right: 160px; float:left">
        <div>
            EMPLOYEE NUMBER:
            <div>
                <input type="text" data-bind="text: EmpNumber" /></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            ROOM:
            <div>
                <input type="text" data-bind="text: Room" /></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            DATE:
            <div>
                <input type="text" data-bind="text: Date" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 40px;">
        <div>
            START TIME:
            <div>
                <input type="text" data-bind="text: StartTime" /></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            END TIME:
            <div>
                <input type="text" data-bind="text: EndTime" /></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            NOTES:
            <div>
                <input type="text" data-bind="text: Notes" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the div EditReservation will show up but the fields are empty.

i am sure that the data-binds for each field are correct since it matches the returned json data when properly mapped,

the problem is, ko.applyBindings is not executing that's why i think the fields are empty when loaded...

what could be the errors?

Comment: What does your ajax response look like?  It will be easier to give you an answer if you have your sample code running on jsfiddle.

Comment: What errors do you see in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Input fields should use the 'value' binding rather than the 'text' binding. If the properties could have not been mapped you would have seen an exception thrown by knockout in the browser console.